# How do I insert text into a Monaco Editor?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I have a monaco code editor embedded in my app.

How do I programmatically insert text on a particular line?

```
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "// First line\nfunction hello() {\n\talert('Hello world!');\n}\n// Last line",
    language: "javascript",

    lineNumbers: false,
    roundedSelection: false,
    scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
    readOnly: false,
    theme: "vs-dark",
});
// how do I do this?
editor.insertText("FOO");
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using the [executeEdits API](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ICodeEditor.html#executeEdits)

```
var line = editor.getPosition();
var range = new monaco.Range(line.lineNumber, 1, line.lineNumber, 1);
var id = { major: 1, minor: 1 };             
var text = "FOO";
var op = {identifier: id, range: range, text: text, forceMoveMarkers: true};
editor.executeEdits("my-source", [op]);
```

Comment: Just like to say that there's also a method off the model called `pushEditOperations`, which is similar to `editor.executeEdits`. Quite helpful if you have multiple models and want to update one that isn't the editor's current model.

Answer (score 32):

A more robust solution would be to use the [Selection](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/classes/monaco.Selection.html) API instead of Position

```
var selection = editor.getSelection();
var id = { major: 1, minor: 1 };             
var text = "XXX";
var op = {identifier: id, range: selection, text: text, forceMoveMarkers: true};
editor.executeEdits("my-source", [op]);
```

If there is already a pre-selected text in the editor, the insert will replace it, which is in my opinion, the correct behavior.

Comment: `Selection` itself inherits from `Range`, so no need to recreate it.

Comment: Not part of what the original poster asked, and only correct if there is a direct connection to a user action.

Comment: To be even more robust, `getSelections()` should be used, as monaco supports multiple lines edition/insertion.

Comment: What exactly is "my-source" in this example?

Comment: the `id` and related `identifer` are not required; can alternatively use`var op = {range: selection, text: text, forceMoveMarkers: true};`; see https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/interfaces/editor.ICodeEditor.html#executeEdits

Answer (score 12):

To insert text at the cursor, there is this very simple way.
I use it a lot to make Snippet toolbars:

```
editor.trigger('keyboard', 'type', {text: "test"});
```

It will replace the text if text is selected.

And you can also add multiple line text this way:

```
editor.trigger('keyboard', 'type', {text: `text on
multiple
line`});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues implementing this with react and typescript so hopefully this could help someone.

```
import Editor, { Monaco, OnMount } from '@monaco-editor/react';
import { editor, languages } from 'monaco-editor';

...

const CustomEditor: React.FC = () => {

    const [monacoInstance, setMonacoInstance] = React.useState<editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor | null>(null);

    const insertText = (text: string) => {
        if (monacoInstance) {
            const selection = monacoInstance.getSelection();
            const id = { major: 1, minor: 1 };
            const op = {
                identifier: id,
                range: {
                    startLineNumber: selection?.selectionStartLineNumber || 1,
                    startColumn: selection?.selectionStartColumn || 1,
                    endLineNumber: selection?.endLineNumber || 1,
                    endColumn: selection?.endColumn || 1,
                },
                text,
                forceMoveMarkers: true,
            };
            monacoInstance.executeEdits('my-source', [op]);
        }
    };

    const editorMount: OnMount = (editorL: editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor) => {
        setMonacoInstance(editorL);
    };

...

        <Editor
            onMount={editorMount}

...

        <StyledButton // styled comp
            onClick={() => {insertText('inserted text');}}
        >
            insert text
        </StyledButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more natural solution (as mentioned above) can be the to use the [executeEdits](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ICodeEditor.html#executeEdits) method that comes with monaco and use a specific range with line numbers and column numbers, because in the examples they are always using the first line:

```js
const startLineNumber = 15 // Line number in which the content will start being typed
const startColumn = 5 // Column number in which the content will start being typed
const endLineNumber = 18 // Line number in which the text will finish
const endColumn = 25 
const text = "This is the new text" // The content going to be added


const range = new monaco.edito.Range(startLineNumber, startColumn, endLineNumber, endColumn); // It will go to the specific position of the editor

const id = { major: 1, minor: 1 }; // Required generic id

const editOperation = {identifier: id, range: range, text: text, forceMoveMarkers: true}; // The operation going to be performed

monaco.editor.executeEdits("custom-code", [ editOperation ]); // Runs the instruction
```

The good part of the code above is that it can **add, delete, update and replace** existing code, so it will be very efficient and the end user will see it like if he/she was typing.